# How to limit on focus to be invoked just once

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, textinput

I have a text input that I use for some search in database:

```
<input type="text" ... onkeyup="searchProducts(event);" onfocus="searchProducts(event); ...
```

The problem is when I have `onfocus` in this input it constantly call `searchProducts` function and that's the problem.
I want to do this just one time when input got focus.
Maybe I should use something else instead `onfocus`?
I use clean **JavaScript** no **JQuery**.

Comment: Maybe `onkeyup` calls `searchProducts` all the time?

Comment: jQuery is also "clean" JavaScript :)

Comment: @Amberlamps yes but I meant I don't use it :)
@dfsq when I remove `onfocus` it never get in a loop for search.

Comment: `onfocus` is only triggered once. Every other time `searchProduct()` is triggered by `onkeyup`.